# React + Webpack bundling - if node_modules are excluded 'require is not defined' in browser

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle

I'm learning React and I'm trying to use it with Webpack, but I'm facing the following issue:

If I use this webpack config, the node modules don't get excluded and the bundling process takes 20 second and the bundle's size is over 2MBs (see CLI output below):

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'bootstrap-loader',
    './src/index.js',
    'style!css!./src/style/style.css'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [
          'style',
          'css?modules&importLoaders=2&localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
          'postcss',
          'sass',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        loader: 'file'
      },
      // Bootstrap 3
      { test:/bootstrap-sass[\/\\]assets[\/\\]javascripts[\/\\]/, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: CLI output 1]

...
[image]

However, if I add the following two lines to my config and use nodeExternals the bundle becomes small and runs quickly, although its not working because in the browser I'm getting the error **'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'**:

```
  ...
  target: 'node', // important in order not to bundle built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
  externals: [nodeExternals()]
  ...
```

[image]

What am I missing here? I suppose the browser throws this error, because react doesnt exist on client side anymore after I exclude node_modules, however I suppose the node_modules shouldn't be bundled. 
Please, find the repo of my small project with the problem here:
https://github.com/sznrbrt/messageboard-react

**SOLUTION:**

**Two different ways are either passing an excluding or including option for the loader with a regex of /node_modules/**

```
...
exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
...

  ...
  { test: /\.js?$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    ],
    loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory',
  },
  ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is to add `exclude: /node_modules/` field inside `module.loaders`.

Adding target: 'node' means pack this code to run in node.js environment where node specific global variable is included like `require`. This is the reason it does not run in browser.

Comment: do i have to add exclude to  all loaders or just one